# MDS errors: "DiskStore: No block in wakeup" and "Ignored bogus fetch for MDSQueryWithBlockTask"

Tags: macos, mac, spotlight, mds

I've been getting tons of these entries in my system log. I can't find any indication of what they mean.

I assume it's a problem with spotlight somewhere, and I've rebuilt the spotlight indexes, but the error persists. Searching for the text of these errors yields nothing.

Does anyone know what this is?